# How can i parse JSON in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, post

I have this database model: [image]

And this code:
View:

```
function post() {
        var groupName = $("#GroupNameInput").val();
        var teacherName = $("#TeacherNameInput").val();
        var data = {
            "Teacher": { "Name": teacherName },
            "Name": groupName
        };
        $.post("/CreateGroup", data);
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateGroup(Group group)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I calling function post with parametors `groupName = "something", teacherName = "abc"`
i have this object is c#:

```
//Some params
Name = "something"
Teacher = {
//some params
Name = null
}
```

Why i havent parametor group.Teacher.Name?
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this in jquery:

```
function post() {
        var groupName = $("#GroupNameInput").val();
        var teacherName = $("#TeacherNameInput").val();
        var data = {
            "Teacher": { "Name": teacherName },
            "Name": groupName
        };
        var JSON_data = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.post("/CreateGroup", JSON_data);
    }
```

And on the server side you can use JsonValue.Parse into a dynamic object (which then you could "translate" to one of your custom objects)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateGroup(FormCollection data)
{
    dynamic values = JsonValue.Parse(data["JSON_data"]); 
    // Do whatever you want with this object
}
```